# Oracle Can connect from client but not from script - invalid user/password

Tags: oracle, vba, database-connection, connection-string, oracle12c

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle DB and i believe the version is 12c, I'm able to connect to the same DB using a client (SQL Developer), but having issues while trying to connect using VBscript which I would like to use as part of my application.

Here is the error message --

```
      **Exception: OraOLEDB - ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**
```

Here is my script that I'm using to connect --

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
'Dim strSQLQuery: strSQLQuery = "SELECT sysdate FROM dual"
Dim strDBDesc: strDBDesc = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)    (HOST = XXX)(PORT = XXX))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME =     XXXX)))"
Dim strUserID: strUserID = "user"
Dim strPassword: strPassword = "pass"
Dim ADODBConnection: Set ADODBConnection =                               CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim strConnection
strConnection = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & strDBDesc & _
            ";User ID=" & strUserID & ";Password=" & strPassword & ";"

ADODBConnection.Open strConnection

If Err <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "An error occurred in Opening Connection: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Source
End If
Set ADODBConnection = Nothing
```

Comment: I'd wager that the username and/or password is different.  Either that or you're trying to connect to a different database from the two applications.

Comment: I submitted an edit to tag VBA in the question so it will reach people who can answer. I had a quick look and the syntax for the call looks right. You could try it with the Oracle service name in strDBDesc instead of the entire connection description. Use TNSPING from cmd prompt to check that your client has the Oracle service name resolving correctly. If that doesn't work, try a different type of Provider connectivity.

Comment: Justin - I checked my credentials atleast 25 times and they seem right !!

Comment: Does the host / port / service point to the same database (eg are trying to connect to a db on "localhost" from different machines ) ? Since you are forming a string from the parameters, does the password contain any of those punctuation separators ?

Comment: or try different provider ? `"Provider=msdaora;Data Source="` http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?40986-Solved-Connect-to-Oracle-Database-using-Excel-VBA

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the password simple or with special character? use an escape sequence or quotes if with special characters.
2. Based on below use "ADODBConnection.ConnectionString = strConnection" in the above snippet and then open the connection.
3. Place break point and see what is being passed as a connection string to the driver.

Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E47955_01/win.121/e18594/using.htm

Comment: Password has a '_' and no other special characters but it has a mix of both upper an lower cases . I have put a connection string and I have verified the script but connecting to other instances and have no issues . The sake password and username has been issued for other instances and there is no issue while connecting using the same script .

Comment: check the connect permission for the user. Cause I don't see any issue with the code. So it should be on this instance or user which fails to connect. Check the connect permission.

Answer (score 0):

All,

i was able to connect successfully after i have download and installed the latest copy of Oracle ODAC from their website.

here are additional details - hope this helps others having a similar issue
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server/